# Symfony 2 Deploying App to Web

Tags: symfony

When deploying symfony2  to the web it still thinks im using local folders for instant..

```
[public]$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
[RuntimeException]
Unable to write in the "C:/Users/brent.french/Documents/www/clients/app/app/cache/prod" directory
```

I tried following http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html with no success any ideas?

Comment: you need to pass your folder cache/prod as 775 (i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FROM SSH :

**USING ACL ON A SYSTEM SUPPORTING chmod +a**

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
rm -rf app/logs/*

sudo chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
sudo chmod +a "yourname allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

**USING ACL ON A SYSTEM NOT SUPPORTING chmod +a**

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:yourname:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:yourname:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

**Without using ACL**

just after your opening PHP tag in : "app/console", "web/app.php" and "web/app_dev.php" add :

```
umask(0002); // This will let the permissions be 0775
// or
umask(0000); // This will let the permissions be 0777
```

Source : Symfony Doc

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the app/cache/* folder to remove any old information and this fixed it.